# Nullpointer Exception while loading property file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

Currently I have a work flow where I have multiple cucumber feature files and for same we have written/maintained different properties files. A single flow is run and browser is been closed and later for second task a new browser is open.

For example:
**Package_feature**

1. Feature_file1 (Flow ->Login ->some task ->logout ->1st browser closed)
2. Feature_file2 (Flow ->New browser opens ->Login ->some task ->logout ->2nd browser closed)
3. Feature_file3 (Flow ->New browser opens ->Login ->some task ->logout ->3rd browser closed)

**Properties_files**

1. Properties_file1_for feature_file1
2. Properties_file2_for feature_file2
3. Properties_file3_for feature_file3

**Now,**
I want to continue my workflow of feature file as below:

1. Feature_file1 (Login -> do some task and later finishing all task call Feature file 2)
2. Feature_file2 (do some task and continue for all task and later move to Feature_file3)
3. Feature_file3 (do some task ->Logout)

I am looking for above scenario to be run in single browser (Login ->All task run ->Logout ->close browser) maintaining a different feature files, properties files. I do not want to launch another browser (some modification required in my current code)

**I tried** with "Background" keyword by getting below:
java.lang.NullPointerException: From properties file:nullkeyword.

Is it due to "driver" instance. Looking for suggestions.

Trace:
Found env to be null and setting it to default: Dev
To change the environments, please add commandline arg such -Denv="Dev" ("Dev" is your environment you want to connect to.) to your gradle command.
Dev.properties

[31mFailed scenarios:[0m
[31msrc/test/resources/features/path/Feature_file1.feature:9 [0m# eg -eg

2 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m, [32m1 passed[0m)
17 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [36m4 skipped[0m, [32m12 passed[0m)
1m41.010s

**java.lang.NullPointerException: From properties file:nullkeyword: featuremenu.menu not found in the envConfig properties file.
    at com.ex.Utilities.replaceParameterizedValuesInString(Utilities.java:131)**
    at baseSetupConfig.BaseSetup.replaceParameterizedValuesInString(BaseSetup.java:98)
    at stepDefinition.GUIStepDef.iShouldSeeElement(GUIStepDef.java:346)
    at ?.I expect "exex" text in element "{{featuremenu.menu}}"(src/test/resources/features/path/Feature_file1.feature:6)

Comment: Add trace and line of code causing issue.

Comment: @niharika_neo Please find below the trace:

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code e.g. `Utilities.java:131` and check why the properties file is `null`. See the exception message `... From properties file:null ... `. All other messages seems to be from your custom code.

Comment: @SubOptimal - Yes thank you. I have debug the code and found that when my first browser launch the driver and other stuff is getting initialized but later while trigger of second feature, the same browser does not find the driver and other things declared which often goes as null and hence unable to access property file.